# Не запускается цикл CMD

Tags: windows, cmd, for

Хочу прогнать все wav файлы в папке командой:

```
whisper --language ru --model large -o ./result -- .\name_file.wav
```

Пишу цикл вместе с этой командой:

```
FOR %%a IN ("C:\Users\Max\Desktop\Оценка звонков\Записи звонков\*.wav") DO (whisper --language ru --model large -o ./result -- .\%%a)
```

И мне выдает следующую ошибку:

```
строка:1 знак:4
+ FOR %%i IN ('C:\Users\Max\Desktop\Оценка звонков\Записи звонков\*.wav ...
+    ~
Отсутствует открывающий знак "(" после ключевого слова "for".
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingOpenParenthesisAfterKeyword
```

Как решить проблему?

Пробовал вместе %% писать %, но все такая же ошибка.

Отдельно команда whisper работает.

В командной строке я уже нахожусь в папке `C:\Users\Max\Desktop\Оценка звонков\Записи звонков`

Comment: Решить проблему просто - перестать путать cmd и powershell  Если команда для cmd, то надо там ее и запускать. А в PS другой синтаксис.

Comment: помогло + надо оставить один знак %